# Poker cards combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, poker

**Question**

Suppose you draw 7 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that you draw *three pairs* of cards if

1. the three pairs must have distinct denominations?
2. the three pairs don't necessarily have distinct denominations? (two cases)

Note: Do not include the possibility of having exactly three cards of any denomination.

**My attempt**

For #1, my solution is $$probability = \frac{{{\binom{4}{2}}^3\binom{13}{3}(46)}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$
And I'm unsure what #2 could be.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you don't want to include the possibility of having exactly three cards of any denomination, the $46$ in #1 is not correct... there are only $40$ possibilities remaining for the final card.  For #2, you may also have four cards of one denomination, two cards of a second denomination, and a final card of a third denomination.  Can you see how to calculate that probability?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For #2, if four cards are in the same denomination, when choosing that 4 cards would it be $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ or would it simply be $\binom{4}{4}$?

Comment: ${{4}\choose{4}}$.... it doesn't matter how you pair them up, if you have two pairs of the same denomination, you have all fours cards of that denomination.  (And if it didn't matter, it'd be ${{4}\choose{2}}{{2}\choose{2}}$.)

Answer (score 1):

For second,

We either choose $3$ denominations or $2$. For pairs from $3$ denominations, it is same as the first and for pairs from $2$ denominations, we first choose the denominations and then we choose which we will have $4$ cards of and which $2$ ($2$ ways do so).

So, probability $\displaystyle = \frac{\binom{13}{3} \ {{\binom{4}{2}}^3 \cdot 40} + \binom{13}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot {\binom{4}{2}} \cdot 44}{\binom{52}{7}}$

Also for first, instead of $46$ choices for the $7$th card, you should have only  $40$ choices (as $12$ cards cannot be considered - no three cards can have the same denomination).

Comment: For case two of the second part where two pairs are in the same denomination and one pair in a separate denomination, would it be $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}*2*44$ or would it be $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{4}*44$? Your equation seems to be missing a pair (I might be wrong tho)

Comment: the last one but we need to multiply that by two as any of the two denominations can be $2$ cards and other $4$.

Comment: The reason I did not write $4 \choose 4$ explicitly as it is simply $1$. The reason ${4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} {2 \choose 2}$ would not be correct is because then we are getting into arrangements where order matters. That is not what we are doing in the first term. That is not what we are doing even in the denominator. We are only selecting $7$ without specifying any order.

Comment: ... thus we count ways to obtain 2 from 13 kinds with 2 from 4 suits in 1 from these (the other kind to have all 4 suits), and 1 from the remaining 44 cards not of those kinds. Hence: $\binom{13}2\binom 21\binom 42\binom{44}1$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for additional commentary.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I really appreciate it! I am still a bit confused on why we need to multiply by 2 in the second part though. Why do we need to add that times 2?

Comment: Let's say we choose two denominators Ace and King. Now if you choose 2 from Ace and 4 from king that is 4C2.4C4. But you can also have 2 from king and 4 from Ace.

Comment: Ah I see thanks!